# In angular and Spring application my logout Function not working?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

In my Spring for session i have used redis server.
and right now i am using Angular 7.

Here code 
1>nav-compo.ts
  After clicking logout button Function direclty call here logout()

```
 logout()
  {


    this.loginService.logout().subscribe(
      res =>
      {
        location.reload();
      },

      err =>
      {
        console.log(err);
      }
    )

  }
```

2>Here loginService

```
import { MyAccountComponent } from './../components/my-account/my-account.component';
import { AppConst } from './../constants/app-const';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

   private serverPath:string =AppConst.serverPath;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router:Router) { }

  sendCredential(username: string, password: string) {
    let url = this.serverPath+'/token';
    let encodedCredentials = btoa(username+":"+password);
    let basicHeader = "Basic "+encodedCredentials;
    let headers = new HttpHeaders ({
        'content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization' : basicHeader
      });


    return this.http.get(url,{headers:headers});

  }


  checkSession(){
    let url = this.serverPath+'/user/checkSession';
    let headers = new HttpHeaders ({
        'x-auth-token' : localStorage.getItem('xAuthToken')

    });
    console.log("Value of token at check Session ",localStorage.getItem('xAuthToken'));
    return this.http.get(url,{responseType:'text'});
  }

    logout(){
      let url = this.serverPath+'/user/logoutUser';
      let headers = new HttpHeaders ({
        'x-auth-token' : localStorage.getItem('xAuthToken')

      });
      return this.http.post(url,'',{responseType:'text'});
     // return this.http.post(url,'',{headers:headers});

    }




    ngOnInit() {
      //Called after the constructor, initializing input properties, and the first call to ngOnChanges.
      //Add 'implements OnInit' to the class.

    }

}
```

3>And Final backend part (LoginResource )

```
package com.bookstore.resource;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class LoginResource {

    @RequestMapping("/token")
    public Map<String,String> token(HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest req){

        System.out.println(req.getRemoteHost());

        String remoteHost=req.getRemoteHost();
        int port =req.getRemotePort();

        System.out.println("This is remoteHost:Port Number"+remoteHost+":"+port);
        System.out.println("This is GetRemoteAddr"+req.getRemoteAddr());

        return Collections.singletonMap("token",session.getId());


    }


    @RequestMapping("/user/checkSession")
    public ResponseEntity checkSession()
    {

        System.out.print(HttpStatus.OK);

        return new ResponseEntity("Session Activated!",HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/user/logoutUser",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity logout()
    {
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        System.out.println("louout");
        return new ResponseEntity("Logout done",HttpStatus.OK);
    }



}
```

4> Filter class

```
package com.bookstore.config;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Component
public class RequestFilter implements Filter{



    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, x-auth-token");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        System.out.println("value of request "+request.getMethod());
        if(!(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS"))) {
            System.out.println("At if");
            try {
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Pre-fight");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allowed-Methods", "POST, GET, DELETE");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "authorization, content-type, x-auth-token, " +
                    "access-control-request-headers,access-control-request-method,accept,origin,authorization,x-requested-with");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        }
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}


}
```

- After Clicking logout button my page will reload but noting happen.it will be same as previous page.
- if i put {headers:headers} in return filed out loginservice.logout()
  then  error will come up

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
>     at http.js:109
>     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
>     at HttpHeaders.lazyInit (http.js:103)
>     at HttpHeaders.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpHeaders.init
> ```
>
> (http.js:167)
>           at HttpHeaders.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpHeaders.forEach
>   (http.js:236)
>           at Observable._subscribe (http.js:1436)
>           at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe
>   (Observable.js:43)
>           at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe
>   (Observable.js:29)
>           at subscribeTo.js:21
>           at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:11)

Answer (score 0):

You've got this code for logging out:

```
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
```

I would have expected something like this:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
if (auth != null){    
    new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
}
```

Just to be clear, it's not a routing issue or permission issue? You do indeed see that the '/user/logoutUser' RequestMapping is indeed being reached on the server side?

Comment: Ah - angular problem.